# About Box Contents

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I came across this About dialog of the Sparrow Mail app. Is this possible 'out of the box' within the AppDelegate or is this a real 'window' I will have to develop so I can replace the default Apple generated one with the credits?

[image]

Comment: Your question about EDSidebar is more appropriate as a separate question posed to the owners of the project or posted here (as a separate question) with **much** more information about what you tried and what failed. I've gone ahead and removed it so your question has a single point and doesn't get you down-voted / closed (for being all over the map and combining two unrelated questions into one). The first can be answered; the second is to vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The About Box gets its content from the "Credits" RTF file that is present in all app-level projects created by Xcode templates. You can edit it within Xcode or in any rich text editor (including hyperlinks, formatting, etc.).

The icon is taken from the app's bundle settings (Info.plist) and requires no extra work beyond setting the app's icon (so don't include it in your RTF file). Similarly, the version is taken from the bundle settings. In other words, everything below the icon and version line comes from the rich text file.